# plainToClass overload choice cause a type error

Tags: angular, typescript, class-transformer

I'm working on an angular project. Most of the code is not mine, but I need to get it compiled.

While the following example compiles on one machine, it generates an error on others.

```
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

plainToClass(MyClass, myObject).filter(true);
```

The error that I got upon running `ng build` is the following:

```
error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'MyClass'.
```

`myObject` is declared as `any` but contains an array. If I change the code as follows, it works.

```
plainToClass(MyClass, myObject as any[]).filter(true);
```

The problem is that the same method is scattered all over the project.

I wonder why the same piece of code is working on one machine but not the other.

On both machines (same `package.json`) version 0.2.0 of class-transformer is used.

It seems that one overload of the method is picked up on one machine, but not the other. And this happens rather randomly.

Is there a way to solve this problem globally?

Comment: Have you checked that `tsconfig.json` is the same on both machines?

Comment: @john yes both files are identical (i actually checkout the whole project form git, and tsconfig.json is tracked).

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure how to help you, but here are som thoughts that might help. The `plainToClass`-method is defined as

```
export function plainToClass<T, V>(cls: ClassType<T>, plain: V[], options?: ClassTransformOptions): T[];
export function plainToClass<T, V>(cls: ClassType<T>, plain: V, options?: ClassTransformOptions): T;
export function plainToClass<T, V>(cls: ClassType<T>, plain: V|V[], options?: ClassTransformOptions): T|T[] {
    return classTransformer.plainToClass(cls, plain as any, options);
}
```

source: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/src/index.ts

When you define myObject as `any` the `plainToClass` does not know which implementation to use, and therefore the compiler might think that you are using
`export function plainToClass<T, V>(cls: ClassType<T>, plain: V, options?: ClassTransformOptions): T;` (which does not have the `filter`-method because it does not return an array).

If you do declare `myObject` as `any[]`, or use the `plainToClass` like this: `plainToClass<any[]>(MyClass, myObject).filter(true); // added <any[]>` it might work, as the compiler knows which method to use (the one returning an array), and you can use `.filter` on it.

Another thing that may help is to create your own `plainToClass` function, which only returns an array, and uses the method from the `class-transformer` package/library.

This is just some guessing, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Your guess makes total sens to me. It would mean that the typescript transpiler picks a different overload on each machine. This leaves me wander if there isn't some indeterminism baked into Typescript nature?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. Please let me know if you figure it out :)